# IIS Reverse Proxy to Tomcat uppercase path

Tags: iis, tomcat, reverse-proxy, iis-8, tomcat7

We have an application being served by Tomcat 7 on port 8080. We want users to use SSL. So we are using IIS 8 as a Reverse Proxy to proxy connection from port 443 to port 8080.

This is what we are trying to achieve: 
https://app.example.com ==> app.example.com:8080/AppName/

Below is the URL Rewrite rule

```
<rule name="Tomcat Reverse Proxy" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false"/>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/AppName/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

When this rule is executed instead of proxying the request IIS does a redirect and I see *http://localhost:8080/AppName/* in the browser's address bar.

The problem is the **AppName**. IIS URL Rewrite module doesn't like uppercase in the action. However, Tomcat 7 is URL case sensitive and if I use "appname" in the rewrite rule Tomcat throws a 404.

Is there any way that I can get IIS to play nice with uppercase url in a rewrite?